# Image fade-in on exposure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dreamweaver

How do I fade in an image once it's in view? I'm trying to make my website responsive, so having it fade in on the amount of pixels scrolled won't do. I need it to be exposed depending on the percent scrolled. Or if there's a way to have it fade in when it's in the field of vision?

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind("scroll", function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
    $("#bluprintdesign").fadeIn();
} else {
    $("#bluprintdesign").stop().fadeOut();
}
```

Right now what I have going on is it fades in when scrolled 300px and fades out if you scroll back up. I like that, but I want it in percentages so it's responsive to all screen resolutions.

Thank you!

Comment: There is no need to make the change you are suggesting and will no effect on whether or not your website is responsive. Read more about [the method](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) here.

Comment: This plugin might be doing what you are looking for: https://scrollrevealjs.org/

Comment: @c0deNinja I tried using it but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function `showImages()` that will measure your `$.scrollTop()` + `$(window).height()` to establish the scroll point of the bottom of the viewport, and will add a class to hidden images when half of the image has passed the bottom of the viewport. I'm calling it on `$(document).ready();` and `$(window).on('scroll');` so that it will load images in the viewport on page load and as you scroll.

Using `opacity: 0` instead of `display: none` (what `$.fadeIn()/$.fadeOut()` will toggle) allows the image to still take up space in the document, allowing you to calculate it's height (needed to know when half of the image is in view) without having to do anything tricky, and will also maintain the page layout when the image fades in, versus the page jumping around if you toggle `display`.

There are also libraries that will do this for you. [jQuery waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) is a popular one.

```js
function showImages() {
  var $window = $(window),
    thresh = $window.scrollTop() + $window.height();
  $('img:not(.show)').each(function() {
    if (thresh > $(this).offset().top + ($(this).outerHeight() / 2)) {
      $(this).addClass('show');
    }
  });
}
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  showImages();
})
$(function() {
  showImages();
})
```

```css
section {
  height: 200vh;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
img {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
</section>
<section>
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
</section>
<section>
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
</section>
```